# Path not drawing to canvas in android app

Tags: android, canvas, path

I load float values on two List arrays on a thread.
Once the values have been loaded, the arrays are set to two MainActivity static List arrays.

The values load perfectly into the List arrays. In my DummyDraw class which extends Drawable and overrides onDraw(), I am able to draw circles based on the values located inside the MainActivity List arrays, but when I try
to create a path object and load the values to the path object, and afterwards try to draw the path, it won't draw. Here's the code inside onDraw():

```
//inside onDraw() on DummyDraw class which extends Draw-able:

//in the constructor:
path = new path();

//inside onDraw():
for(int u = 0; u < MainActivity.valueList.size(); u++){
float x = MainActivity.valueList.get(u);
float y = MainActivity.valueList2.get(u);
if(u==0)path.moveTo(x,y);else path.lineTo(x,y);
//canvas.drawCircle(x,y,0.5f*densityMultiplier,points);
}

canvas.drawPath(path,points);// this doesn't draw anything to the screen
```

Any ideas or suggestions, thanks.

Comment: did you set attributes to `Paint` object (`points`)?

Comment: yes of course. @Adithya I have been reading and I must implement path.rQuadTo(). I am trying to implement this method now, but no success.

Answer (score 0):

After much trial and error and reading about the quadto and rQuadTo methods, I found a way to create a very excellent approximation of a smooth curve for my graphing function needs:

using the notion of previous and current point on the List arrays:

```
for(int u = 0; u < MainActivity.valueList.size(); u++){
float x = MainActivity.valueList.get(u);//current point: x value
float y = MainActivity.valueList2.get(u);//current point: y value

if(u!=0){
float previousX = MainActivity.valueList.get(u-1);
float previousY = MainActivity.valueList2.get(u-1);
float middle1 = (previousX + x)/2f;
float middle2 = (previousY + y)/2f;
path.moveTo(previousX,previousY);
path.quadTo(x,y,middle1,middle2);
path.lineTo(x,y);
canvas.drawPath(path,points);//points is the name of my paint object
path.reset();//this is probably the most important line for it to work    
}

}
```

the code above will iterate through two arrays that holds x and y coordinates and create a very excellent looking smooth curve. However, upon zooming into my view I can see some slight blurriness in my curve. Does anyone know what should I do with my paint object to eliminate this blurriness?